# Implement partial Framework css on old website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, semantic-ui

I know bootstrap, semanticUI, foundation, etc.

My new project is a part of an old website. and we want to start implementing the new features with a normal css framework. 
So, how do to implement a partial view? 
lets say a  with a framework css without rebuilding all the website from scratch ?

```
<body> <!-- regular old website css -->
  <div class="old"></div>
  <div class="everything-in-here-using-css-framework"></div>
</body>
```

is that possible? which framework support this ?

Comment: What do you want like partial view ? Because foundation uses [Grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html) which is a good way to start

Comment: I have a full website working, with lots of css. but its old css. and i want to use a css framework on a small part of the website i am rebuilding. 
as part of the new UI i want implement on the website.

Comment: And what do you want to display ? We need more details ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't fully understand but i think you can follow these steps:

1. make sure there are no matching conflicting class names with your framework (in foundation for example: columns, small-12, etc...)
2. include the framework's CSS file (you can link to a cdn just for testing)
3. start writing some new html elements and see how it goes.
4. if crashes occure (probably they will) start to change the old elements name - for instace add "old-" to every class you have.

another approach could be to move the existing project to SASS, then wrap the old CSS in a container like this

```
.old {
    header { ... }
    div { ... }
}
```

and put all the framework styles in something like this:

```
.new {
     ...
}
```

I think we'd be more helpful if you'll give more details.